# No encuentro como hallar los mayores

Tags: java

Estoy dándole y no encuentro como hallar el numero de estudiantes con notas mayores al promedio

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n, cont = 0;
    double acum = 0, p_est, p_gen = 0;

    //IN
    System.out.println("Ingrese numero de estudiantes ");
    n = sc.nextInt();

    //PROCESS
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese promedio del estudiante " + i + " : ");
        p_est = sc.nextDouble();

        acum = acum + p_est;
        p_gen = acum / n;

        if (p_est > p_gen) {
            cont++;

        }

    }

    System.out.println("El promedio general es: " + p_gen);
    System.out.print("Estudiantes superiores: " + cont);
    System.out.println("");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cree una `variable` llamada `max` la cual tomara el valor del promedio mas alto que se valla ingresando, luego lo mostrara por consola.

**Aquí dejo el código con la función para saber cual es el mayor:**

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n, cont = 0;
    double acum = 0, p_est, p_gen = 0;
    double max = 0;    
    //IN
    System.out.println("Ingrese numero de estudiantes ");
    n = sc.nextInt();

    //PROCESS
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese promedio del estudiante " + i + " : ");
        p_est = sc.nextDouble();

        acum = acum + p_est;
        p_gen = acum / n;

        if (p_est > p_gen) {
            cont++;

        }
        if ( max<p_est){
            max = p_est;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("El promedio general es: " + p_gen);
    System.out.println("Estudiantes superiores: " + cont);
    System.out.println("Estudiante con promedio mas alto: " + max);
    System.out.println("");

  }
}
```

[image: Compilado]

Comment: te entiendo pero eso solo seria para calcular el mayor de todo, lo que no logro hallar es cuantos son los mayores que el promedio general, probare con eso que me dices.

Answer (score 5):

Primero necesitas obtener el promedio y después comparar con cada uno de los estudiantes. Puede usar un arreglo. Intenta de esta manera:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n, cont = 0;
    double acum = 0, p_gen = 0;

    //IN
    System.out.println("Ingrese numero de estudiantes ");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    double [] promedios = new double[n];

    //PROCESS
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese promedio del estudiante " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        promedios[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        acum = acum + promedios[i];
    }
    p_gen = acum / n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(promedios[i] > p_gen)
           cont ++;
    }

    System.out.println("El promedio general es: " + p_gen);
    System.out.print("Estudiantes superiores: " + cont);
    System.out.println("");

}
```

Comment: aun no se usar arreglos :(

Comment: @iSony Este problema necesita de arreglos para solucionarse. Tienes que consultar los promedios de los estudiantes 2 veces: Una para calcular el promedio general y otra para saber quiénes tienen más promedio que el general. La única forma de hacerlo si no sabes cuántos estudiantes hay es con un arreglo.

Comment: ya amigo, ya lo hice con arreglos, gracias...

Answer (score 1):

Crea una variable que almacene el promedio y luego compárala con todos los estudiantes.

**Ejemplo**

```
public class PromedioEstudiantes
{
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void procesarCaso()
    {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de estudiantes: ");
        int numeroEstudiantes = input.nextInt();

        double[] estudiantes = rellenarArreglo(numeroEstudiantes);
        double promedio = calcularPromedioEstudiantes(estudiantes);
        int estudiantesSuperiores = obtenerEstudiantesSuperiores(estudiantes, promedio);

        System.out.println("El promedio es: " + promedio);
        System.out.println("Hay " + estudiantesSuperiores + " superiores al promedio");
    }

    private double[] rellenarArreglo(int numeroEstudiantes)
    {
        double[] estudiantes = new double[numeroEstudiantes];
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroEstudiantes; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Ingrese promedio del estudiante " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            estudiantes[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        return estudiantes;
    }

    private int obtenerEstudiantesSuperiores(double[] estudiantes, double promedio)
    {
        int estudiantesSuperiores = 0;
        for (double estudiante : estudiantes)
        {
            if (estudiante > promedio) estudiantesSuperiores++;
        }
        return estudiantesSuperiores;
    }

    private double calcularPromedioEstudiantes(double[] estudiantes)
    {
        double sumaNotas = 0.0d;
        for (double estudiante : estudiantes)
        {
            sumaNotas += estudiante;
        }
        return sumaNotas / estudiantes.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new PromedioEstudiantes().procesarCaso();
    }
}
```

Si necesitas saber qué estudiantes tienen qué promedio, usa un [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).